# How to add a bootstrap form element in asp.net content page

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a bootstrap form in asp.net content page(.aspx). but it gives me an error regarding **"Element form must not be nested with in a element form"**

```
But i want to use the form element for a Login purpose in the page.
```

```
   <div class="container">
    <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
     <form>
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="email">Email:</label>
             <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
         </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
     </form>

   <%--  --%>

</asp:Content>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: how about `<form class="form-group">` instead?

Answer (score 1):

All asp webpages are already in a form, so you don't need the form tag, all you can do is instead of using, you can see the form tags at your main master page  `<form>` you can use `<div class="form">` hope this helps also for the best result 
you should use `CssClass` instead of `class`  in asp tags when adding the styling classes. e.g `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox14" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>`

Answer (score 1):

you have simply use

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>

         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="email">Email:</label>
             <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
         </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear.

Remove the extra form tags `<form>` and `</form>` from your code. Beside that your form did not post anywhere - use the asp.net form to post to code behind, you do not need other form there.